# How to force Visual Studio to refresh list of remote git branches in Team Explorer-Branches?

Tags: git, visual-studio, team-explorer

Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 doesn't update remote branches in Team Explroer - Branches section. This means that whenever somebody adds a branch on remote or remove I can't see it through Team Explorer. Instead I am forced to use Source Tree and then magically Visual Studio notices the new branches. I click refresh button like a maniac and I tried following commands in Package Manager Console:

```
git remote prune origin --dry-run
git config remote.origin.prune true
```

it does nothing or at least not what I am asking.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to trigger a `git fetch` from Visual Studio (which Sourcetree has been doing up until now)

In Visual Studio 2017 Team Explorer go to the "Branches" section, right click the Master branch and select "fetch". You should now be able to see the new remote branches.

Comment: This should be accepted as answer, worked for me in VS2017.

Comment: @PhillippeSantana Accepted it.

Answer (score 8):

Proper way to refresh remote branches is

```
git fetch -p
```

because

```
git fetch
```

does not remove non existing branches.

Comment: Worked great in VSCode, Thanks!